# Url para pedir token para Comprobantes Electrónicos de Hacienda no retorna respuesta

Tags: curl

Estaba probando pedir el Token con esta petición de curl como lo muestran [los docs de Hacienda](https://atv.hacienda.go.cr/ATV/ComprobanteElectronico/docs/esquemas/2016/v4.3/Guia_IdP.pdf)

```bash
curl -X POST "https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rutstag/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=api-stag" \
--data-urlencode "username=cpj-3-101-261506@stag.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr" \
--data-urlencode "password=W$/JX/AS@K);1]I;u|+6" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=password"
```

Pero no estoy recibiendo ninguna respuesta del servidor. Alguien ha tenido este mismo problema o podría apuntarme qué estoy haciendo mal?

PD: en ese snippet, tanto el username como el password son los que vienen por defecto en el ejemplo de los [docs](https://atv.hacienda.go.cr/ATV/ComprobanteElectronico/docs/esquemas/2016/v4.3/Guia_IdP.pdf) de Hacienda, pero igual cuando los sustituyo con mis credenciales obtenidas de ATV no obtengo ninguna respuesta.

Comment: Un error??? nada aparece??? se queda esperando eternamente???

Comment: @gbianchi no hay error, no se queda esperando eternamente. simplemente la petición se hace y se termina y no existe respuesta alguna. pero ya encontré la solución. la documentación está desactualizada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los docs están desactualizados, el url que aparece es este `https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rutstag/protocol/openid-connect/token` sin embargo el url que actualmente está trabajando es `https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token`

En el url que aparece en los docs, el path después de realm es `rutstag`, el verdadero sería `rut-stag` agregándole un guión.